# Jenkins: Some plugin or setting corrupts PATH environment variable

Tags: jenkins

We have Jenkins Master 2.121.2 with 3 Jenkins Slave nodes. Recently we have encountered the following error:

[ssh: not found in $PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKCB9.png)

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@gitlab.com/company/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: /tmp/ssh6561150012866430021.sh: 6: /tmp/ssh6561150012866430021.sh: ssh: not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After analysis we have discovered the $PATH environment variable is getting corrupt somehow:

```
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
GIT_ASKPASS=echo
HUDSON_URL=http://jenkins.company.com/
HUDSON_COOKIE=fead3b34-f36e-4cb6-875b-2ab9462b78d5
JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=24409b12678d95d1
SSH_ASKPASS=/tmp/pass5551091293893472212.sh        
GIT_SSH=/tmp/ssh3633673669866483540.sh
HUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
JOB_BASE_NAME=company-project
PATH=/usr/lib/git-core:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/bin
DISPLAY=:
GIT_SSH_VARIANT=ssh
JENKINS_URL=http://jenkins.company.com/
JOB_URL=http://jenkins.company.com/view/company/job/project/
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=24409b12678d95d1
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
JOB_DISPLAY_URL=http://jenkins.company.com/view/company/job/project//display/redirect
JOB_NAME=company-project
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64
PWD=/
```

We can not understand which setting change or some plugin setting change caused this.

When I run this command from SSH terminal it works fine, because $PATH variable on VM where Jenkins Master installed has correct value with /usr/bin in it and stuff like that:

```
ssh git@gitlab.com/company/project.git
```

Comment: I would try to look for the new PATH string within the configuration files.

Comment: There isn't enough content in your question to be able to tell what's causing the issues with `PATH`.  If you are using Pipeline (i.e. Jenkinsfiles), could you please update your question with the contents of your Jenkinsfile?  Otherwise, could you please post a screenshot of your job configuration?

Comment: This happens before Pipeline (Jenkinsfile), I mean before running Build Job. The screenshot I have posted is from Maven-type job. It happens on Jenkins Master. From UI I'm trying to add Git repository, Git client plugin tries to connect to git repository https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/CliGitAPIImpl.java .

Comment: When I run this command from SSH terminal it works fine, because $PATH variable on VM where Jenkins Master installed has correct value with /usr/bin in it and stuff like that.

Comment: I think this question is related somehow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763421/jenkins-2-x-slave-agent-variables-in-pipelines